sequelize: many to many relationships select where multiple criteria
I have 3 tables. Product, Category, ProductCategories. I need you to take a product with several categories. How can I do it?
@Table({ timestamps: false })
export class Product extends Model<ProductAttributes, ProductCreateAttributes> {
    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    name: string;

    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    preview: string;

    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    cost: number;

    @BelongsToMany(() => Category, { through: { model: () => ProductCategories } })
    categories: Category[];
}

@Table({timestamps: false})
export class Category extends Model<CategoryAttributes, CategoryCreateAttributes> {
    @Column({allowNull: false})
    name: string;

    @BelongsToMany(() => Product, {through: {model: () => ProductCategories}})
    products: Product[];
}

@Table({ timestamps: false })
export class ProductCategories extends Model<ProductCategoriesAttributes, ProductCategoriesCreateAttributes> {
    @ForeignKey(() => Product)
    @Column
    productID: number;

    @ForeignKey(() => Category)
    @Column
    categoryID: number;
}

I tried to do this:
return this.product.findAll({
            include: {
                model: Category,
                through: {
                    attributes: [],
                },
                where: {
                    ...(options.categories && {
                        id: {
                            [Op.or]: [...options.categories]
                        }
                    })
                },
            },
             group: ["Product.id", "categories.id"],
             having: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'Product.id'), '=', options.categories.length)
        });

But the count function does not work as expected when grouping is performed by several columns, but I cannot perform grouping by one column because I get an error

This is the only solution I could come up with:
const identifiers = await this.product.findAll({
        attributes: ["id"],
        include: {
            model: Category,
            attributes: [],
            through: {
                attributes: []
            },
            where: {
                id: categories
            },
        },
        group: ["Product.id"],
        having: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('COUNT', '*'), '=', categories.length),
        raw: true
    }).then(array => array.map(item => item.id));

return this.product.findAll({
        include: {
            model: Category,
            through: {
                attributes: []
            }
        },
        where: {
            id: identifiers
        }
    });


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
